# Loading project gets Server Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, firefox, server, wampserver

When I load a PHP project in a WAMPServer, the feedback is "Server Not Found".

```
Windows 8
WampServer 2.5
MySQL 5.16.17
Apache 2.4.9
Firefox
```

Firefox can't access the server. What is the problem?
And if you have any alternative to WAMPServer, please advise.

Comment: Try writing your post as if you need to provide information about your problem to people who cannot read your mind.   Don't assume people will know relevant details that contribute to your problem unless you bother to tell them.

Comment: wampserver dose not excute myProject ..icopies my projects folder to c:/wamp/www/ . And its apear on my local host page . But when iclicked it iget "server not found "

Comment: This post should explain why and how to configure WAMPServer properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 0):

> Click on project and get server not found

Start All Services of wamp